# Move Quickbooks Online Company to the Development Site

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml

Anyone know how to move a live Quickbooks Online company to the Test site?

I think the address for the test site is:
https://qbo.idnbeta.quickbooks.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that there is no way to effectivly do this.  One has to download the CSV backup from their production QBOE system and import it to a 'local' desktop installation of QB, then import THAT company when creating the idnBeta QuickBooks Online Edition company.

Bah.